# 色空間と表色系の違いは？

Tags: 機械学習

私は機械学習に関する研究を行っています。

色を表す方法として「色空間」という用語を使っている論文と「表色系」という用語を使っている論文があると思います。どちらがより正しい用語なのでしょうか。
私は「色を数字に変換するシステム」を表しているので、「表色系」の方が正確だと考えています。

Comment: 機械学習で使われる、色を表す方法の表現として、英語では"color space"と"color system"、日本語では「表色系」と「色空間」の違いという事でしょうか？

Comment: それぞれに意味があって、正しいかどうかは対象とする論文によるのでは？ [色空間 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%89%B2%E7%A9%BA%E9%96%93)

Comment: とりあえず英語の文献では、photography stack exchangeとResearch gateの類似の質問を貼っておきます。[What is the difference or relation between a Color Model and a Color Space?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/what-is-the-difference-or-relation-between-a-color-model-and-a-color-space), [What are the fundamental differences between color space and color model?](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_are_the_fundamental_differences_between_color_space_and_color_model). 調べた限りでは日本語ではwikipediaのページが該当していると思うのですが、原色を赤緑青として、色を表現する際に数学的に定式化してモデルを考えるのが表色系、液晶ディスプレイ、インク、絵具などの媒体を通して具体的に表示できる色が色空間だと思います。

Answer (score 2):

色彩工学分野が直接対象でなければ、画像認識・画像生成などの機械学習タスクの文脈での 色空間(color space) と 表色系(color system/model) は同義扱いで十分かと思います。
（もちろん、該当論文内で2つの用語を使い分けているようなら話は別ですが...）

いずれも、ある色(color)情報を3次元ベクトル＝3次元色空間上の点として取り扱うという観点では同じです。この3次元空間の3軸の取り方にはRGB（赤・緑・青成分）やHSV（色相・彩度・明度）といったバリエーションがありえますが、空間同士は相互変換が可能です。

表色系の方がいくぶん実践的なニュアンスを持っており、たとえば「[マンセル表色系](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%82%BB%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0)」はHSV色空間に基づきますが、HSV値そのものではなくコード（例`7PB 4/10`）で色を表現します。商品の色を統一するといった工業デザイン分野利用を想定しているため、厳密なHSV値よりもより分かりやすいコード体系が必要とされます。